# Broadcast receiver as way to allow other people's apps and services to send data to my app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, instruments, broadcast

I have an always-on app which needs to receive e.g. Blood-Glucose readings from a home medical instrument. I would like to invite other programmers to write these apps. When a Blood-Glucose reading is ready they should send a Broadcast Intent with "BG" 7.23 for example. Are there any examples of this kind of "Open API" available to learn from?
Is there any downside to publishing an action android:name = "a.b.c.ClassName" ?
Can the new instrument programmers add their own fieldnames to the Extras?

Any examples around?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about Intents.
Intents are the way to pass data between apps.
The other apps will launch an Intent and you'll have a receiver that's registered to this intent.

You can have a look at this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html